# how to insert javascript code that is disabled for mobile devices and only works on desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, desktop

I'm trying to insert the following javascript code in order to make my folders clickable, but i only want this to work on a desktop and be disabled for a mobile device. I've been searching this for hours and haven't been able to find a solution that works with my code. Optimally, I would like it to activate/disable the code based on a whether the folder is being clicked/touched, but if I could do it by screen size, that would work too. Thanks in advance for your help

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.main-nav li a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == 'Photography') {
        $(this).attr('href','http://www.vaughngooding.com/overview');
      $(this).attr('onclick','true');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you try to detect touch device instead??? Anyway in your code, `$(this).attr('onclick','true');` doesn't make sense (or i'm missing something)

Answer (score 1):

```
 function isMobileDevice(){
isMobile = (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) ? true : false;
return isMobile;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure this doesn't handle all possible mobile device and anyway once new device will emerge, this could be outdated

Comment: I'm using this code in my live app and till now I didn't get any issue. If any device which you are talking about, please let me know.

Comment: I'm not thinking about any specific device but it is usually bad to check for useragent: https://css-tricks.com/browser-detection-is-bad/  And here, OP seems to target specifically touch device, not all touch device are mobile one. I guess the question was poorly asked

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but if you are using php as backend you can use this library [MobileDetect](http://mobiledetect.net/) to check if it's mobile/desktop/tablet etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var isMobile = false; //initiate as false
// device detection
if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent) 
    || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0,4))) isMobile = true;

$(function() {
  if(!isMobile){
     $('.main-nav li a').each(function () {
       if ($(this).text() == 'Photography') {
         $(this).attr('href','http://www.vaughngooding.com/overview');
         $(this).attr('onclick','true');
       }
     });
  }
});
```